# programmatically set select type custom field in Liferay 6.2

Tags: java, liferay-6.2

I have created a structure in liferay which has custom fields associated to a DLFileEntry. This structure has custom:
- text fields
- integer fields
- number fields
- dropdown list field

I can programmatically set all these fields, except for the dropdown list, when uploading a document (programmatically) in liferay.

So, let's say that this dropdown list field created through admin console has the name "select-name-liferay". This dropdown list has 3 options:

- key "Option1" -> value: "option1"
- key "Option2" -> value "option2"
- key "Option3" -> value "option3"

  As input in my code I will have

value "option2" and the name of the liferay custom field ("select-name-liferay")

What I do this:

```
Map<String, Fields> fieldsMap = new HashMap();


        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : customFields.entrySet()) {
           ....all other custom fields are put in the map

                targetFields.put(new Field("select-name-liferay",  "a string"
           ....
        }
        fieldsMap.put(structure.getStructureKey(), targetFields);
```

Then I use Liferay DL Utils to save the file passing fieldsMap to it. All the fields that are not the select are set correctly, but I cannot seem to be able to set the value for the dropdown list.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

try to set the value as

```
targetFields.put(new Field("select-name-liferay",  "[a string]"
```

Comment: looks like your answer is incomplete

Comment: Thank you, your answer solved my issue. For anyone having the same type of problem, when building the fieldsMap, in case you need to set an option for a "select" type Field, you need to put a map whose key is the field name, and whose value is the option-value surrounded by [ . Such as this:

targetFields.put(new Field("select-name-liferay",  "["+aString+"]"